# Array of Objects in C++

Tags: c++

i am trying to do chess with openGL c ++, for now i have created the pawn object, where its constructor takes an unsigned int parameter. So I tried to create an array of these pawns, and the only working way I've found to do this is this :

```
Pawn *pawn[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    pawn[i] = new Pawn(Unsigned int var);
}
```

To call a function of pawn [0], for example, I have to do this :

```
pawn[0]->function(parameters);
```

This is the Pawn class :

```
class Pawn
{
private:

    float vertices [16] = {
        //position       //text coord
        -0.08f, -0.10f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.08f, -0.10f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.08f,  0.10f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.08f,  0.10f,   0.0f, 1.0f

    };

    GLuint indices[6] {
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 2, 3
    };

    unsigned int shaderID, VBO, VAO, EBO, texture;

public:

    glm::vec2 Position = glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);

    Pawn () {}

    Pawn(GLuint shaderID) {
        ...
    }
    
    ~Pawn() {
         ...
    }

    void setTexture();

    void draw (glm::vec2 position);

};
```

I also tried this :

```
Pawn pawn[8];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    pawn[i] = Pawn(shaderID);
}
```

but when i run it doesn't work.

I was wondering if this method is efficient or not, and if so, why it works, since I didn't understand it. Thanks for your help

Comment: What speaks against `Pawn pawns[N]`, i.e. an array of objects instead of an array of pointers?

Comment: Maybe show us your `Pawn` class as well? There are several ways to create arrays of objects in C++. Which ones have you tried and why didn't they work out?

Comment: If the only constructor your Pawn class has takes an int, you can't default-construct an array of them, so you wouldn't be able to do Pawn pawn[n]. You could potentially do Pawn pawn[n] = {1, 2, 3}; (up to whatever n is)...

Comment: This should be orf use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @George or use `placement-new` instead.

Comment: @Raildex Or std::array...

Comment: Efficient in what way? You should elaborate on that... Also, what did you not understand?

Comment: @George i tried to do Pawn pawn[2] = { int, int } and it works. Thanks everyone for the help.